# How can I get an specific element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a row of boxes with products inside. They all differ in name since all have the product's id attached with a

```
<div id="plus" name="<?php echo $_item->getId()?>" onclick="greenUp()">+</div>
```

That is the + sign to add that is going to be placed in top of each product.

```
var count = 0;
function greenUp() {
    var idProduct = document.getElementById('plus').getAttribute('name');
    if (count == 0) {
        console.log(idProduct);
        jQuery('input[name='+idProduct+']').addClass('selected-plus');
        count = 1;
        console.log(count);
    }
    else {
        jQuery('input[name='+idProduct+']').removeClass('selected-plus');
        count = 0;
        console.log(count);
    }
}
```

This is the function I am trying to apply to green up each box when clicked, however, when I click the first box It works, but if I click the second box the first one will get turned off, like if they where only one element. 
Any ideas will be appreciated.

EDIT:
For future references
All the answers below made a lot of sense for me, I don't know why it didn't work. 
What I resolve to do was assign the value of the id directly to the function as below:

`<label for="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId()?>"><div id="<?php echo $_item->getId()?>" class="plussign" onclick="greenUp(<?php echo $_item->getId()?>)">+</div></label>`

and change the function as below:

```
        var setup = new Array();
    function greenUp(id) {
        var idProduct = id;
        if (typeof(setup[id]) == 'undefined' || setup[id] == 0) {
                jQuery('#'+idProduct).addClass('selected-plus');
                setup[id] = 1;
            }
        else{
                jQuery('#'+idProduct).removeClass('selected-plus');
                setup[id] = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. Use `class="plus"` instead.

Comment: you don't even need the ids: `onclick="greenUp(this)"`, then access `this.name` to get the id value.

Comment: Usage of the restricted selector ">" or even .siblings() might be of use to you.

Comment: None of this worked..

Comment: `div` elements don’t have a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

With reference of comment on question. This would be this. Also ID should be unique within the page. You can use class for this.

```
<div id="plus" name="<?php echo $_item->getId()?>" onclick="greenUp(this)">+</div>

var count = 0;
function greenUp(clickedDiv) {
    var idProduct = clickedDiv.getAttribute('name');
    if (count == 0) {
        console.log(idProduct);
        jQuery('input[name='+idProduct+']').addClass('selected-plus');
        count = 1;
        console.log(count);
    }
    else {
        jQuery('input[name='+idProduct+']').removeClass('selected-plus');
        count = 0;
        console.log(count);
    }
}
```

With Jquery Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/zLwytk9v/3/

Comment: `greenUp(this.name)` would be more efficient since you don't need `clickedDiv` anywhere.

Comment: if this is not working then try this I have make it with jquery and your function. https://jsfiddle.net/zLwytk9v/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div name="<?php echo $_item->getId()?>" onclick="greenUp()">+</div>
```

As you are using JQ, do like this:

```
var count = 0;
function greenUp() {
    var idProduct = $(this).attr('name');
    if (count == 0) {
        console.log(idProduct);
        jQuery('input[name='+idProduct+']').addClass('selected-plus');
        count = 1;
        console.log(count);
    }
    else {
        jQuery('input[name='+idProduct+']').removeClass('selected-plus');
        count = 0;
        console.log(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ChitiDahan did you try to console.log(idProduct) to check if it gets the attr corrctly?

Comment: Yes, it actually gave me an error. It was saying that $(..).Attr() wasn't an available function, or something like that..

Comment: `$(..).attr()` while not `$(..).Attr()`